# What to use to measure internet latency? Ping, lft, mtr, traceroute - I tried them all

Tags: linux, macos, network-monitor, internet

I'm unable to measure latency to a server.
I've tried ping, traceroute, lft and mtr with the default parameters.

I always get a partial result:

```
rob@Robs-2019 ~ % ping seau.gssv-fastlane-prod.xboxlive.com
PING seau.gssv-fastlane-prod.xboxlive.com (20.46.108.166): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2

sudo mtr seau.gssv-fastlane-prod.xboxlive.com
Robs-2019.local (192.168.0.22) -> seau.gssv-fastlane-prod.xboxlive.com                                                                                                                                                    2021-12-06T23:40:43+1300
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                                                                                                                                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 192.168.0.1                                 0.0%     3    1.6   1.6   1.6   1.7   0.1
 2. 202-56-33-250.nownz.co.nz                   0.0%     3    3.0   4.1   3.0   5.0   1.0
 3. (waiting for reply)
 4. 202-56-33-132.nownz.co.nz                   0.0%     3    5.6  13.1   4.1  29.5  14.3
 5. as8075.auckland.megaport.com               66.7%     3    4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0   0.0
 6. ae29-0.icr01.syd03.ntwk.msn.net             0.0%     3   36.5  30.8  27.8  36.5   4.9
 7. 13.106.239.35                               0.0%     3   40.6  41.1  40.6  41.5   0.5
 8. 13.106.162.14                               0.0%     3   38.9  39.3  38.8  40.3   0.9
 9. 13.106.165.191                              0.0%     3   38.6  38.8  38.4  39.5   0.6
10. 13.106.238.8                                0.0%     3   40.7  40.9  40.1  42.0   1.0
11. (waiting for reply)
```

Can someone recommend a tool or tell me which parameters I should use in one of these tools?
I'm using macOS.

Comment: That site just doesn't respond to pings [from either Mac or Win, which by default use different methods] Traceroute dies at 64 hops, with no data coming back as soon as you hop beyond msn. This is very probably by design, reading between the lines. They just don't want you to do that. if you want to measure it, presumably you'd have to do it from inside whatever game you're running, assuming it has that kind of debug level.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand that some servers don't respond to ICMP packages but I thought some other tool could use TCP or whatever to ping. Like with LFT, but I couldn't make it work too.